# Hypothesis testing MLE for $H_{0}: R\mu=r$

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, inference

As in [Multivariate normal distribution - hypothesis testing MLE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/450763/multivariate-normal-distribution-hypothesis-testing-mle).

Suppose $X_{1}, X_{2},\ldots,X_{n}\in R^{p\times 1}$ are i.i.d. observations from a multivariate normal distribution $N(\mu,\Sigma)$ where $\Sigma$ is known.

Use the likelihood ratio procedure to produce a test statistic for  $H_{0}: R\mu=0$ versus $H_{1}: R\mu\neq 0$.
Assume $R$ is a given matrix of size $m\times p$ with rank $m$.

What is the MLE of $\mu$ under $H_0$? How does one go about answering this?

Comment: @StubbornAtom Can you give me hints? I cannot solve this problem...

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I have added lots of details...

Comment: As to your Q about MLE of $R\mu$, if it is $R\mu=R\bar{X}$, **YES**.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/438778/question-about-casella-and-bergers-proof-of-mle-invariance

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen But what is the MLE of $\mu$ under $H_0: R\mu=0$?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen $R$ is nonrandom matrix of size m×p with rank m.

Comment: @Bob: $R\mu=0$ sas that the vector $\mu$ is orthogonal to the rows of $R$. Thta is, $\mu$ belongs to the orthogonal complement of the row space of $R$. So you will need the orthogonal proyector onto that space ... and apply that to the mean vector $\bar{X}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$ is known, maximizing the log-likelihood subject to $\boldsymbol{R}\boldsymbol{\mu} = \boldsymbol{0}_m$ will only involve terms involving $\boldsymbol{\mu}$ in the quadratic form of the multivariate normal density.  Let $\boldsymbol{\lambda} = (\lambda_1, \cdots, \lambda_m)^{\prime}$ denote the vector of Lagrange multipliers.  Then we wish to maximize
\begin{eqnarray*}
Q(\boldsymbol{\mu},\boldsymbol{\lambda}|\boldsymbol{x}_1, \cdots, \boldsymbol{x}_n) = -\frac{n}{2} \boldsymbol{\mu}^{\prime}\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}\boldsymbol{\mu} + n\boldsymbol{\mu}^{\prime}\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1} \boldsymbol{\bar{x}} + \boldsymbol{\mu}^{\prime} \boldsymbol{R}^{\prime} \boldsymbol{\lambda}.
\end{eqnarray*}
The partial derivative of this function with respect to $\boldsymbol{\mu}$ is
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\partial Q(\boldsymbol{\mu},\boldsymbol{\lambda}|\boldsymbol{x}_1, \cdots, \boldsymbol{x}_n)}{\partial \boldsymbol{\mu}} = -n\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}\boldsymbol{\mu} + n \boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1} \boldsymbol{\bar{x}} + \boldsymbol{R}^{\prime} \boldsymbol{\lambda}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Setting the above equal to $\boldsymbol{0}_p$, we can solve for $\boldsymbol{\mu}$ by pre-multiplying both sides by $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$ and performing basic algebraic manipulations.  Specifically,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\boldsymbol{\mu} =  \boldsymbol{\bar{x}} + \frac{1}{n} \boldsymbol{\Sigma}\boldsymbol{R}^{\prime} \boldsymbol{\lambda}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now pre-multiply both sides of the above equation by $\boldsymbol{R}$ and solve for $\boldsymbol{\lambda}$.  Since $\boldsymbol{R}\boldsymbol{\mu} = \boldsymbol{0}_m$, we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\boldsymbol{0}_m = \boldsymbol{R}\boldsymbol{\bar{x}} + \frac{1}{n} \boldsymbol{R}\boldsymbol{\Sigma}\boldsymbol{R}^{\prime} \boldsymbol{\lambda}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\boldsymbol{\lambda} = -n \left(\boldsymbol{R}\boldsymbol{\Sigma}\boldsymbol{R}^{\prime}\right)^{-1} \boldsymbol{R}\boldsymbol{\bar{x}}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Plugging this back into the equation for $\boldsymbol{\mu}$, we find that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\boldsymbol{\mu} = \left[\boldsymbol{I}_p - \boldsymbol{\Sigma}\boldsymbol{R}^{\prime}\left(\boldsymbol{R}\boldsymbol{\Sigma}\boldsymbol{R}^{\prime}\right)^{-1} \boldsymbol{R}\right] \boldsymbol{\bar{x}}.
\end{eqnarray*}